# Regular expression to remove JavaScript double slash (//) style comments

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to do remove JavaScript comments via a regular expression in C# and have become stuck. I want to remove any occurrences of double slash `//` style comments.

My current regex is `(?<!:)//[^\r\n]*` which will catch all comments and prevent matching of `http://`. However, the negative lookbehind was lazy and of course bit me back in the following test case:

```
var XSLPath = "//" + Node;
```

So I'm looking for a regular expression that will perform a lookbehind to see if an even number of double quotes (`"`) occurs before the match.  I'm not sure if this is possible.  Or is there maybe a better way to do this?

Comment: Always use [Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Updated based on comments)*

It looks like this works pretty well:

```
(?<=".*".*)//.*$|(?<!".*)//.*$
```

It appears that the [test cases in Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=9566749d-d656-4334-98e2-094020306076) show that it'll match comments the way I think it should (almost).

For instance, it'll completely ignore this line:

```
var XSLPath = "//" + Node;
```

But it's smart enough to match the comment at the end of this line:

```
var XSLPath = "//"; // stuff to remove
```

However, it's not smart enough to know how to deal with 3 or more quotation marks before the comment.  I'm not entirely sure how to solve that problem without hard-coding it.  You need some way to allow an even number of quotes.

Comment: However, that's easily changed via `(?<![":])//.*(?!")$`

Comment: Fails on something like this:
"text // more text"

Comment: @LFSR Consulting -- Nicely done, your modification seems to solve that problem.  Hope you don't mind but I updated my answer with your fix.

Comment: Joel, it seems you'd need some way to allow an even number of quotes before the slashes, but not an odd number. Hmm...

Comment: I updated my regex again.  This will match comments even if two quotes appear before it, but not 1 quote.

Comment: The regex looks good - thanks for all the effort, it's much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome.  It's still not perfect, but I'm glad it works for you.

Comment: If you really want an edge case, try it on this JS snippet:
`var regex = /foo\//; //<- that first // is not a comment : )`