# Regular expression for a string that ends with '/'

Tags: javascript, regex

The regular expression for a string that ends with '/' is the following:

```
str.match(//$/) -- javascript syntax
```

but the // makes the compiler think it's a comment. how to work around this?

Comment: what about this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569295/regex-to-remove-javascript-double-slash-style-comments

Comment: Oh god, so many people typing the same thing but no one checking their answer first!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must escape the final `/` so the interpreter doesn't think it terminates the RegExp literal:

```javascript
str.match(/\/$/);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the slash:

```
str.match(/\/$/)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the escape character (`\`) to specify a literal / as in:

```
 str.match(/\/$/);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to escape the slash

```
str.match(/\/$/);
```

If you want to match a string that ends with slash, you may want to include the actual string too;

```
str.match(/.*\/$/);
```

Comment: " you may want to include the actual string too" <-- no need at all. If you want to see if an input ends with a /, you only have to look for a / followed by the end of input ($).

Comment: Yes, but if you want to use the actual strings returned by the matches, they're not very useful without it.