# How can I read JSON content with a comment with Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json.net

In order to install an external extension into Google Chrome browser, I try to update a Chrome external extension JSON file. Using `Json.NET` it seems to be easy:

```cs
string fileName = "..."; // Path to a Chrome external extension JSON file

string externalExtensionsJson = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

JObject externalExtensions = JObject.Parse(externalExtensionsJson);
```

but I get a `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException` saying:

```cs
"Error parsing comment. Expected: *, got /. Path '', line 1, position 1."
```

when calling `JObject.Parse` because this file contains:

```cs
// This JSON file will contain a list of extensions that will be included
// in the installer.

{
}
```

And comments are not part of JSON (as seen in *[How do I add comments to Json.NET output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495718/how-do-i-add-comments-to-json-net-output)*).

I know I can remove comments with a regular expression (*[Regular expression to remove JavaScript double slash (//) style comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569295/regular-expression-to-remove-javascript-double-slash-style-comments)*), but I need to rewrite JSON into the file after modification and keeping comment can be a good thing.

Is there a way to read JSON content with comments without removing them and be able to rewrite them?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Json.NET only supports reading multi-line JavaScript comments, i.e. /* commment */

**Update:** Json.NET 6.0 supports single line comments

Comment: Thanks but I have no choice: Google Chrome provides a file named "external_extensions.json" containing single line comments and I must complete it.

More generally, Json is often used as configuration file where comments (single and/or multi lines) can be added by users. We have no choice: we can be faced with the need to read each comment (and ideally rewrite it). And I liked to be able to use Json.Net to do it.

Do you think it can be a possible evolution?

Comment: Replacing with regex was not a completely satisfactory solution. Taking it into account into Json.Net was what I was hoping. Thanks!

Comment: Damn. Most justified un-accept I've had so far. Curse you! :)

Comment: @tofutim: They're safe from crude "chomp"-like minifiers

Comment: I still get errors with comments though. Like this `Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: Comment`

Answer (score 4):

If you are stuck with JavaScriptSerializer (from the System.Web.Script.Serialization namespace), I have found that this works good enough...

```cs
private static string StripComments(string input)
{
    // JavaScriptSerializer doesn't accept commented-out JSON,
    // so we'll strip them out ourselves;
    // NOTE: for safety and simplicity, we only support comments on their own lines,
    // not sharing lines with real JSON

    input = Regex.Replace(input, @"^\s*//.*$", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);  // removes comments like this
    input = Regex.Replace(input, @"^\s*/\*(\s|\S)*?\*/\s*$", "", RegexOptions.Multiline); /* comments like this */

    return input;
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but it looks to me like these only remove comments that start and end on their own line. you can remove the `^\s*` prefix from both (Multiline may also be unnecessary on the first regex) to remove comments starting on the same line as a value (e.g. `"Prop": "Value" // This is a property` ), and you can remove the `\s*$` suffix from the second to allow a comment to end on a line with data (e.g. `/* Setting */ "Prop": "Value"`). These, however, will only work correctly if no strings in the JSON data contain `//` or `/* */` - (Note: this is all from freehand/manual reading)

Answer (score 3):

You could always convert single-line comments to multi-line comment syntax before parsing...

Something like replace...

```
.*//.*\n
```

with

```
$1/*$2*/
```

...

```
Regex.Replace(subjectString, ".*//.*$", "$1/*$2*/");
```

Comment: I think your regex will match too much. Consider valid json values that have "//" in them:
`{url: 'http://www.forever21.com/Product/Product.aspx?br=f21&category=dress&productid=2000062214',
photo: 'http://www.forever21.com/images/default_330/00062214-02.jpg'}`

Comment: @ScottRoberts True. Unfortunately, we're edging into trying to parse json with regex. And that way lies madness. That said, if someone with better regex skills can fix it, please do.

Comment: I just got bit by http:// in config, after rolling my own regex. Wound up here, among my fellow Damned. :-)

Comment: Though I confess I just amended the regex to be `//[^'"]*$` and told my friends, no single or double quotes in your comments. Madness exactly.