# JObject Error parsing comment

Tags: c#, json

Trying to get some information about a youtube video:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/BDQqSnSEuyk?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=storeInfo
```

The result is JSON.

I try using deserialize it with  JSON.net:

```
JObject JObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(gDataResult);
```

I get this error:

```
Error parsing comment. Expected: *, got /. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

It is because of the single // comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i read json with comment with Json.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316997/how-can-i-read-json-with-comment-with-json-net)

Comment: Regex.Replace(subjectString, ".*//.*$", "$1/*$2*/"); not working, has tried it.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: this is not duplicate, the target thread has nothing to do with JSON-P which the URL points at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be more careful when reading the data file. This is not JSON. This is JSON-P. Even the URL you provided suggests that: note the `callback=storeInfo` at the end.

The JSON-P differs from JSON in that the object is wrapped in a function call:

```
// API callback
storeInfo({"apiVersion":"2.1","..... }}});
```

To be a plain JSON, it needs to be just

```
// API callback
 {"apiVersion":"2.1","..... }}};
```

With this serivce, just use an url of `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/BDQqSnSEuyk?v=2&alt=jsonc` without the 'callback' section and you'll get a normal JSON response.